# How can I convert FLAC to other formats in OS X?

Tags: macos, mp3, flac, audio-conversion

I have a few FLAC files that I'd like to play with iTunes. I would like to retain  the metadata if possible.

How can I convert the files to a format supported by iTunes?

Comment: Normally I'd say SoundConverter, but getting gstreamer running on OS X is No Fun.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can always convert media via [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/), available as a static build for OS X from the [downloads page](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html).

```
ffmpeg -i in.flac -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 -map_metadata 0 out.mp3
```

Set the quality via `-q:a`, which corresponds to LAME's VBR options, 4 being default and 0 being the best quality.

Answer (score 6):

aac:

```
ffmpeg -i file.flac -acodec libfaac -aq 250 file.m4a
```

-aq 400 ≈ 270 kb/s for music, 200 ≈ 210 kb/s, 100 ≈ 130 kb/s.

alac:

```
for f in *.flac; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -acodec alac "${f%flac}m4a"; done
```

mp3:

```
ffmpeg -i file.flac -aq 0 file.mp3
```

-aq 0 corresponds to -V0 in lame.

ffmpeg preserves tags by default but not cover art.

Answer (score 4):

I've used [Max](http://sbooth.org/Max/) with success in the past.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently used [xACT](http://xact.scottcbrown.org/), a front end to several audio manipulation and tagging programs. It can do conversion from FLAC to MP3, AAC and Opus. Here you can see the tab from which you perform the conversion:

[image: xACT screenshot]

The metadata are preserved, as you can see from the Media Information dialogs (taken in VLC) for a FLAC file and its conversion in MP3:

[image: FLAC metadata]
[image: MP3 details]

P.S.: the linked site uses frames, to read a comprehensive description of the program follow [this link](http://xact.scottcbrown.org/release-notes.html).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have ffmpeg installed ([brew install ffmpeg](https://gist.github.com/clayton/6196167))

Go into the directory in terminal.
Run:

```
for f in *.flac; do ff=${f%.flac}.mp3; ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 0 -map_metadata 0 "$ff"; done
```

This should produce a directory of mp3 as well as flac in v0 format

Answer (score 1):

[X Lossless Decoder](http://tmkk.hp.infoseek.co.jp/xld/index_e.html)

This only converts to lossless and non-lossless formats.

You can use it to convert to Apple Lossless that iTunes can play then play that or rip it to whatever lossy format you prefer that iTunes supports.

Comment: The link seems to be dead.

Comment: Working link to download XLD: https://tmkk.undo.jp/xld/index_e.html