# Most practical way to convert 20G of music in flac format to mp3 for itunes

Tags: mp3, flac

from my old windows computer I have around 20G of music in flac format. Now, I got a mac and I would like to add this music to itunes, so I need to convert them to mp3 format.

So, what is the best way to convert a so big music library to mp3?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most practical thing to do is [not convert it](http://www.xiph.org/quicktime/download.html).

Comment: A little confused if this was part of the op's question but, would it be possible to play the .flac files on an iPod?

Comment: Those will not play on an iPod, they would need to be converted to AAC or MP3 first.

Comment: If you don't need to play them on other devices, also check out flukeformac: http://code.google.com/p/flukeformac/

Answer (score 2):

For anyone running OS X and finding this question from Google, I would suggest following the method listed [here](https://superuser.com/a/545687/529900) and using `ffmpeg` in the Terminal.

Install [homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then install [ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MacOSX) and all its libraries:

```
brew install ffmpeg

brew install ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac --with-ffplay --with-freetype --with-libass --with-libquvi --with-libvorbis --with-libvpx --with-opus --with-x265
```

Then within the terminal, navigate to the folder containing the FLAC files to be converted and run ffmpeg's converter with something like this:

```
for q in *.flac; do echo "$q"; ffmpeg -i "$q" -aq 0 "${q%%flac}mp3"; done
```

Credit goes to the original poster of the above command at the linked thread.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert them to Apple lossless. Or use xIph as Ignacio suggests. I got this link from google: [Convert to Apple lossless](http://forums.appleinsider.com/showthread.php?t=73469)